# MacOS update raised EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, react-native

I'm developing an react-native application on M1 Mac.

I recently updated my mac os to beta version Monterey(version 12.0 beta)

After installing the beta version of the mac os i also installed the Xcode(13.0 beta)

Now my app is installed to the iPad simulator but when i open the app, i get the following error.

[image: error log]

Can someone help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like a null pointer dereference, but the cause would be hard to pin down without more details.

Comment: What more details you need @Alexander

Comment: More details on the stack traces, though I don't feel too confident that I could solve it in any case

Comment: It's also happening for Flutter apps running on the simulator

Comment: If you build the app with Xcode, the build process might fail, and it will provide better errors.